# Implementing non-date driven recurrence

Tags: c#, algorithm, recurrence

I am developing an application that essentially prompts users when they need to perform Preventative Maintenance on various pieces of equipment.  Each piece of equipment (call it a tool) has a different recurrence pattern.  Some will be based on time, such as every 90 days, while others are based on other factors such as usage.  For example, a particular tool might need PM after it has been checked out X number of times.

All tools are assigned to an individual so when that user signs into the application I need to display a list of the tools that require PM at that time.  As PM is completed, those items drop off the list and as other circumstance, such as the date changes or the tool is checked back into the crib, tools will be added.

I am starting with the design of the service method that will return this list and am looking for some help with the approach I use to resolve what items are in the list.  For inputs I will have the user's identifier and the current date.  From that I need to query the list of tools and determine based on their recurrance pattern, the last time PM was performed and the events that have taken place since the last PM, whether that item should appear in the list.

Hopefully that makes sense.  I appreciate any thoughts and guidance on how I should approach this logic.

Comment: What part of the design specifically do you need guidance on? The object model and where the "is PM required" should be located?

Comment: The algorithm/logic to resolve what tools should be displayed.  It makes sense to me that each tool should have a RecurrenceType that can be an enumerated list and a RecurrenceValue that is used to determine the frequency. But I am trying to wrap my head around the best way to determine what tools require PM today, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like each Tool is going to have it's own logic for determining whether PM is required or not. So I would define an IEquipment interface with a couple enums, something like this:

```
public enum RecurrenceType
{
    //Values
}

public enum RecurrenceFrequency
{
    //Values
}

public interface IEquipment
{
    bool IsPMRequired();

    RecurrenceType RecurrenceType { get; }
    RecurrenceFrequency RecurrenceFrequency { get; }
    //You may want to choose something other than object, or eliminate this property
    object RecurrenceValue { get; set; } 
}
```

Then each type of equipment would implement the interface, and the logic to determine whether or not PM is required could be implemented:

```
public class Tractor : IEquipment
{
    public bool IsPMRequired()
    {
        //Implement logic here specific to a Tractor
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public RecurrenceType RecurrenceType
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public RecurrenceFrequency RecurrenceFrequency
    {
        get { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }

    public object RecurrenceValue
    {
        get
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        set
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Then your logic to use these objects would be something like:

```
List<IEquipment> equipment = new List<IEquipment>();
//Populate equipment
List<IEquipment> display = equipment.Where(e => e.IsPMRequired()).ToList();
//Display the equipment that needs PM
```

It might also make sense to have a base class for Equipment where you put common method/property definitions.

Comment: What's the purpose of the enums if each subclass already has to provide the `IsPMRequired` method? _If_ some specific implementation of the method requires such helpers, then define them for that class; but on the general case they don't seem justified.

Comment: @herenvardo - I'm sorry you feel that way. :) Joking aside, the enums are simply properties that provide additional information about the type. This information can be useful in areas other than IsPMRequired. For example, if you are iterating through a List<IEquipment>, you will not know the type without testing it first, but you WILL know the RecurrenceType, RecurrenceFrequency, etc, because they belong to the interface.

Comment: I have to admit that I'm not sure why I'd have multiple enums, can you explain your thinking? In my mind RecurrenceType would be something like Days or Uses. Then I'd just need RecurrenceValue to be the 'count.'  So to have a PM cycle every 90 days, I'd have RecurrenceType.Days and RecurrenceValue = 90.

Comment: You may not have ANY enums, or you could have many more, this was just an example. You will have to tailor the idea to fit your use case.

Comment: So, as I suspected, these enums are useful for the context on which the answer will be used, but they aren't really _part of the answer_. From my experience (on here and many other places), I have seen that separating the answer from the side stuff can help a lot, as it prevents confusing the asker. Phrases like "as a side comment...", "you may also want to ...", "you should also think about..." and so on usually work well for this cases. Overall, I think the content of your answer is quite good, but it may be harder to understand than if you had separated or even omitted the side stuff.

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of closure, I thought I'd update the post with the results of my effort although I am giving credit for the answer to both Brandon and Florian for sending my on the right path.

I ended up with an interface, as Brandon suggested, called IHaveRecurrence defined as follows:

```
public interface IHaveRecurrence
{
    DateTime? LastOccurrence { get; }
    RecurrenceType RecurrenceType { get; }
    Int32 RecurrenceValue { get; }
    Boolean IsDue();
}
```

My MaintainableTool (base) class now implements this interface.  The IsDue method is implemented by delegating to the Recurrence class:

```
public Boolean IsDue()
{
    return Recurrence.IsDue(this);
}
```

Recurrence is an abstract base class as suggested by Florian. I have several subclasses such as DailyRecurrence, WeeklyRecurrence, etc.  Each of the subclasses corresponds to one of the values in the RecurrenceType enumeration and implements the appropriate logic to determine if PM is due based on the RecurrenceValue and LastOccurrence properties via the IHaveRecurrence interface.

Recurrence uses the internal RecurrenceFactory class to resolve which subclass to use:

```
internal sealed class RecurrenceFactory
{
    public Recurrence GetRecurrence(RecurrenceType type)
    {
        switch (type)
        {
            case Daily: return new DailyRecurrence;
            :
        }
    }
}
```

And Recurrence is implemented as:

```
public abstract class Recurrence : IDisposable
{
    public static Boolean IsDue(IHaveRecurrence recurringObj)
    {
        using (var recurrence = RecurrenceFactory.GetRecurrence(recurringObj.RecurrenceType))
        {
            return recurrence.GetIsDue(recurringObj);
        }
    }

    protected abstract Boolean GetIsDue(IHaveRecurrence recurringObj);
}
```

Then, for instance, the DailyRecurrence class is implemented as:

```
public sealed class DailyRecurrence : Recurrence
{
    protected override Boolean GetIsDue(IHaveRecurrence recurringObj)
    {
        if (recurringObj.LastOccurred.HasValue)
            return recurringObj.LastOccurred.AddDays(recurringObj.RecurrenceValue) <= DateTime.Now;

        return true;
    }
}
```

I like this model as it is highly extensible, encapsulates the logic required to resolve each recurrence pattern and keeps my business object clean.

Answer (score 1):

I would define an abstract class Recurrence that looks like this:

```
abstract class Recurrence
{
      public abstract bool IsDue(DateTime dateAndTime);
}
```

Now make Recurrence a property of Equipment.

```
abstract class Equipment
{
      protected abstract Recurrence PMRecurrence
      {
            get;
      }

      public bool IsPMDue(DateTime dateAndTime)
      {
             return PMRecurrence.IsDue(dateAndTime);
      }
 }
```

Then you could define appropriate subclasses of Recurrence like TimeRecurrence, UsageRecurrence and assign instances of them to appropriate subclasses of Equipment like Hammer, Tractor and implement them as needed. This should provide a good balance of flexibility and maintainability.

Good luck, seems like a challenging task!

Comment: Nice answer, definitely inheritance and abstraction are the way to go, but... would you mind fixing that `Publich` on your first snippet? (should be `public`: lower-case and no trailing `h`).

Comment: I like this idea. Sort of an implementation of the Specification pattern and would allow me to encapsulate the logic so it's easier to maintain and extensible.

Comment: To take it a step further, I'd probably have a RecurrenceFactory that accepts the RecurrenceType enumerated value from the Equipment instance and return the appropriate subclass.

Comment: Sorry for the typo. Writing code with an iPhone is a bit hard :) I would keep it simple and just instantiate the appropriate Recurrence instance from within the Equipment instance. But if course it's up to you!